# Flicked US-ASCII items

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

**my us-ascii items are flicked, some have error info.**

```
var usascii = {item: []};
usascii.item[null];
write.asciiFunction("usascii");
flick["usascii"];
```

Cannot flick usascii: command not found

Comment: use `// flick` than `flick`.

Comment: We are missing some context to help you. What is flick?

Comment: flick is to flash a command

Comment: Are you sure this is even javascript? Or maybe you are using a framework? Because with the syntax you are using it seems that flick is an object and you are trying to retreive the "usascii" item. Which makes no sense with your error

Comment: the created usascii item cant be flicked, command not found: usascii

Comment: the error makes sense